# Problems with BackButtonItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background-image, navigationcontroller

Well, I have a NavigationController with a diferent color and I want the back button to also have a background image, a highlighted background image, and a custom text color. How can I do this? I have tried lots of things but I havent been able to change this backbutton.

Comment: So what specifically have you tried? So that others don't repeat.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to create your own custom button.

- Create a custom UIBarButtonItem that suits your requirement.
- Assign this Custom UIBarButtonItem to the leftBarButtonItem of the NavigationItem.

You can only point to the leftBarButtonItem, since the backBarButtonItem is ReadOnly.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = aCustomBarButtonItem;
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Hope this helps...

**EDIT**

Code that can help :

```
UIButton *aCustomButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[aCustomButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[aCustomButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back2.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[aCustomButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickOfBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[aCustomButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 40)];

UIBarButtonItem *aCustomBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aCustomButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = aCustomBarButton;
[aCustomBarButton release];
```

Comment: and for the navigation to work correctly, you need to put [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; in the method 'onClickOfBack' written by @Roshit.